# Escape character '\' doesn't show in System.out.println() but in return value

Tags: java

In Java, when I replace characters in a `String` with escaped-characters,  the characters show up in the return value, although they were not there according to `System.out.println`.

```
String[][][] proCategorization(String[] pros, String[][] preferences) {
String str = "wehnquflkwe,wefwefw,wefwefw,wefwef"; 
String strReplaced = str.replace(",","\",\""); //replace , with ","
System.out.println(strReplaced);
```

The console output is: `wehnquflkwe","wefwefw","wefwefw","wefwef`

```
String[][][] array3d = new String[1][1][1]; // initialize 3d array
array3d[0][0][0] = strReplaced;
System.out.println(array3d[0][0][0]);


    return array3d;
}
```

The console output is:

> wehnquflkwe","wefwefw","wefwefw","wefwef

Now the return value is:

> [[["wehnquflkwe\",\"wefwefw\",\"wefwefw\",\"wefwef"]]]

I don't understand why the `\` show up in the return value but not in the `System.out.println`.

Comment: because that is how the IDE decides to show it to you. *If* there were no ``\`` then you could rightfully assume that what you in fact have is an array of small strings which would not be true. So to make clear that it is one big string the delimiters `"` are escaped for you.

Comment: I don't understand those downvotes. It's not a bad question.

Comment: "the return value is:" - How are you viewing this return value?

Comment: @xenteros It is bad, it has been asked a thousand times before and will be asked a thousand times again, for every IDE and every language.

Comment: Regarding downvotes, this is SO; pretty much everything gets downvoted.

Comment: @luk2302 if its been asked a thousand times before why not just link one of those as a duplicate?

Comment: @luk2302 why won't you suggest a duplicate? I can't find one. What's more, I have no idea how to search for it although I have some programming experience.

Comment: @luk2302 question about different language won't be accurate dupe as it would be hard find via google

Comment: Please don't just hit downvote, add the reason for downvoting in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Characters in memory can be represented in different ways.

Your integrated development environment (IDE) has a debugger that chooses to represent a `String[][][]` with a single element that contains the characters

```
wehnquflkwe","wefwefw","wefwefw","wefwef
```

as a java-quoted string

```
"wehnquflkwe\",\"wefwefw\",\"wefwefw\",\"wefwef"
```

this makes a lot of sense, because you can then copy and paste this string into java code without any loss.

On the other hand, your system's console, and the IDE's built-in terminal emulator, will output the characters in their normal representation, that is, without any java string-escape-characters:

```
wehnquflkwe","wefwefw","wefwefw","wefwef
```

As an experiment, you may want to check what happens with other "special" characters, such as `\t` (a tab break) or `\b` (backspace). This is just the tip of the [iceberg](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) - characters in Java generally translate into [unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) points, which may or may not be supported by the fonts available in your system or terminal. The IDE's way of representing characters as java-quoted strings allows it to losslessly represent pretty much anything; System.out.println's output is a lot more variable.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println` prints the `String` exactly as it is stored in memory.

On the other hand, when you stop the application flow using a `breakpoint` you are able to look up the values.

Most of the IDEs display escape characters with `\` to indicate that it's just one `String`, not `String[]` in this case, or not to split the `String` into two lines if it contains `\n` in the middle.

Just in case, you still have doubts, I suggest printing `strReplaced.length()`. This should allow you to count characters one by one.

Possible experiments:

```
String s = "my cute \n two line String";
System.out.println(s + " length is: " + s.length());
```